# Mysql Query - Subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I have a table `resources (title, resourceid)` and another table `classifications (title, resourceid, classificationid)`

I want to add the tiles from resources to the classification table, there are multiple rows with same `resourceid` in `classifications`.

When I wrote this query

```
update `classification` 
set `title`= (select title 
              from Resources 
              where Resources.`resourceid` = classification.`resourceid`)
```

I got this error:

> Error - subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping the subquery by title, i.e.:

```
UPDATE classification SET title=(SELECT title FROM Resources
    WHERE Resources.resourceid=classification.resourceid GROUP BY title);
```